# Use of "If you really want to"

Tags: questions, intensifying-adverbs

If somebody says, "If you really want to leave me, then let me know," which reply would be correct in the English language—"Yes I do" or "Yes I really do"?

Comment: The *really* is for **emphasis** in both the question and the answer.

Comment: I don't imagine that either participant in a conversation in which this might arise is going to worry much about idiomatic precision.

Comment: If someone told me, "If you really want to leave me, then let me know," and I really wanted to leave that person, I would say, "Okay, I really want to leave you." I wouldn't begin with "Yes," because the other person's statement isn't a yes/no question—or indeed any question at all. Rather, it's a request to be informed instead of left in the dark. As ScotM notes, the _really_ is there for emphasis, not to mark a radical difference in bottom-line meaning.

Comment: Well, the proper response is either "Yes, I want to leave you" or something like "Please, let's talk about this."  (It's probably not "Let me post this on ESE and see what they say.")

Comment: @HotLicks: I think responding with "Let me post this on ESE and see what they say" shows a commendable concern for the niceties of proper expression on so delicate and significant an occasion as this.

Comment: @SvenYargs - I think it communicates to his significant other that he'd rather play with his computer than talk to her.

Answer (score 1):

Either response is correct. The response to this question largely depends on context and tone of voice through which various meanings can be then implied.